# How to remove line with only numeric values without wildcard removal in Python?

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have a text file that contains numeric and text strings

```
21        05W104222222316011W1KKB            2564 CHURCH STREET
21        05W1045098014                      CHITTOOR PA 17125
                                                  CHECK TRANSACTIONS                            GB KDI01
                                                            TOTALS                                    PAGE 00094    DATE 07/22/21

OPERATION                    ----INPUT NUMBER----       ----REJECTED  TRANSACTIONS----    ------CHECK  EXTRACTS------
COMPANY   CASH ACCOUNT       RECORDS TRANSACTIONS           NUMBER              AMOUNT     NUMBER              AMOUNT

     21      11633                96           24                0                0.00         24            1,059.59

     21                           96           24                0                0.00         24            1,059.59
```

I'm trying to remove the lines that have numeric values(complete row)

```
import re

with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        if not all(i.isdigit() for i in line):
            print(line)
```

**Output**

```
OPERATION                    ----INPUT NUMBER----       ----REJECTED  TRANSACTIONS----    ------CHECK  EXTRACTS------

COMPANY   CASH ACCOUNT       RECORDS TRANSACTIONS           NUMBER              AMOUNT     NUMBER              AMOUNT
```

The above code removes the non-numeric rows as well...

**Expected output**

```
21        05W104222222316011W1KKB            2564 CHURCH STREET
21        05W1045098014                      CHITTOOR PA 17125
                                                  CHECK TRANSACTIONS                            GB KDI01
                                                            TOTALS                                    PAGE 00094    DATE 07/22/21

OPERATION                    ----INPUT NUMBER----       ----REJECTED  TRANSACTIONS----    ------CHECK  EXTRACTS------
COMPANY   CASH ACCOUNT       RECORDS TRANSACTIONS           NUMBER              AMOUNT     NUMBER              AMOUNT
```

I want to remove only the numeric rows without hard codings like removing text between `21` and `1,059.59`. Need to remove lines with numbers dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't just check for **any** digit, you should check if **all** are non-digits (or space). Try something like:

```
if not all(ch.isdigit() or ch.isspace() or ch in ",." for ch in line):
    print(line)
```

Or through regex:

```
if re.match(r"^[\s\d\.,]*$", line) is None:
    print(line)
```

Or checking if any string would fail conversion to float:

```
try:
    list(map(lambda value: float(value.replace(",", "")), line.split()))
except Exception as error:
    print(line)
```

Comment: `i` is not defined?

Comment: @Pluviophile I updated the answer, could you check?